# PDF created with pdfrw addpage by copying from other pdf has no root?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfrw

I have a code:

```
pdf = pdfrw.PdfReader(pdf_template)
pdfs= PdfWriter()

for page in pdf.pages:
   ### here some page manipulation
   pdfs.addpage(page)

pdfs.Root.AcroForm.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(NeedAppearances=pdfrw.PdfObject('true')))
```

I am getting error:

> PdfWriter has no Root

Comment: Probably just an erroneous error message. The reason is clear: As a new PDF, `pdfs` has an AcroForm object, because it does not have any fields yet.

Comment: I solved this using a dirty workaround:
        `buf = io.BytesIO()
        pdfs.write(buf)
        buf.seek(0)
        reopen = pdfrw.PdfReader(buf)
        
        reopen.Root.AcroForm = pdfrw.PdfDict(NeedAppearances=pdfrw.PdfObject('true'))

        buf = io.BytesIO()
        pdfrw.PdfWriter().write(buf, reopen)
        buf.seek(0)`